# Creating a new section of man pages

Tags: macos, man

I have obtained man pages for the GNU Fortran intrinsic procedures ([link](https://github.com/AstroFloyd/man-pages-fortran)). After cloning the repo, the man pages themselves are in a directory `~/Documents/fortran-man-pages/man3f`, and each one is a file ending in `*.3f`, e.g., the `ajdustl` function is documented in `adustl.3f`. I want `man` to be able to "see" these pages, so I have copied them to `/usr/local/share/man/man3f`. In theory, `man` should know to look there since `/usr/local/share/man` is one of the directories listed by `man --path`. But no dice:

```
$ man adjustl
No manual entry for adjustl
$ man 3f adjustl
No entry in section 3f of the manual
$ man -M /usr/local/share/man adjustl
No manual entry for adjustl
$ man -k adjustl
Nothing appropriate
```

This is made even more mystifying by the fact that `man` knows about other pages in that directory:

```
$ man -w gs
/usr/local/share/man/man1/gs.1
```

But what about...

```
$ man -K adjustl
(long pause...)
/usr/local/share/man/man3f/adjustl.3f? [ynq]
```

Aha! So these pages are on the search path for `man -K`, but not `man`? Have I missed a step in trying to install these Fortran man pages? I am on OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan).

Answer (score 0):

`man manpath` may help.

I always put man pages in `~/.config/share/man/...`  This clause in my universal `~/.bashrc` file puts them in the search path.

```
if [ -d $HOME/.local/share/man/man1 ]; then
    which manpath >/dev/null 2>&1  &&  P="$(manpath 2>/dev/null)"\
                                   ||  P="$MANPATH"
    case ":$P:" in
        *:$HOME/.local/share/man:*) ;;
        *) MANPATH="$P:$HOME/.local/share/man"
           export MANPATH           ;;
    esac
fi
```

That is, if `manpath` already knows about it, or `$MANPATH` already includes it, then I do nothing.  Otherwise I create `$MANPATH` from `manpath` if the variable doesn't exist.  And then add my path to `$MANPATH`.

You could change it to `/usr/local/share/man/`.